# After adding user to local desktop Administrators group, how to force permissions immediately without logoff/logon

Tags: windows, powershell, permissions, active-directory

After adding a user to the local Administrators group... even though the user is in the local group, they still don't have effective permissions as a desktop Administrator.  They have to at least logoff/logon or reboot for the permissions to take effect.  I was wondering if there's a way to do this via command-line in a seamless fashion.

This resource:
http://woshub.com/how-to-refresh-ad-groups-membership-without-user-logoff/

says, you can use:

```
klist -li 0:0x3e7 purge
```

However, after I ran that command, it didn't make any difference; I still had to logoff/logon or reboot for effective permissions to take place.

Comment: my understanding is that it SHOULD be impossible to upgrade the user priv token of the _current session_. you can start another session inside the current one with an upgraded token, but you really otta not be able to modify the _current_ session.

Comment: The new security token is picked up at logon so ive never known how to do it. You can try killing explorer and re-opening it using the new creds?

Comment: `klist -li 0x3e7 purge` will get the user new kerberos tickets however this only affects those services using kerberos authentication protocol, any service using any other authentication protocol (iex. NTLM) will require a reboot.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I wonder if I could kill the explorer.exe….then create a new task with “runas /user:username@domain explorer.exe”.  I'm going to try it tomorrow..

Comment: @AbrahamZinala thanks for giving me that idea.  I'll try it tomorrow.

Comment: @MKANET - that may work ... but it seems so very wrong to be able to do it at all. [*grin*]

Answer (score 3):

There are two things in play here:

1. What the local machine thinks your privileges are
2. What other machines think your privileges are when you connect to them

Purging the ticket cache with `klist purge` will remove your user ticket cache. This will affect (2), in that when you go try and communicate with another service you must first get a new TGT, which is the thing that actually contains your group membership information. This is why your membership information is cached for 'a while', i.e. because the TGT sticks around for a while, and when you ask for a ticket to another service, the Domain Controller literally just copies the contents of the TGT to the newly requested ticket, and that TGT can exist for a week or more.

Getting a new TGT will always return exactly what the DC thinks your membership is.

Affecting (1) is more complicated. Windows stores this information in what's called an NT Token, which is immutable for the lifetime of a logon session. The NT Token gets your group membership during logon. [Windows asks the DC for that information](https://syfuhs.net/what-happens-when-you-type-your-password-into-windows), and copies it into the NT Token on receipt. This is why it appears as though your membership doesn't change, that is, because Windows hasn't gone off to get your new membership information and hasn't refreshed your NT Token (because it can't, because it's immutable).

As it happens though, a logon session is not forever, and actually only exists between session *unlocks*. Your membership information will get refreshed *shortly after* a lock/unlock once it communicates with DC.

Comment: Thank you for giving such a complete and informative answer.  I'm not sure I understand the last couple of sentences, do you mean lock/unlock of Windows desktop?  I tried that, it didn't make any difference.  If you didn't mean that.. how can I instigate lock/unlock of a session?  Is the only option to completely logoff then logon?

Comment: Yes, lock the desktop and unlock it. It should work, but if it doesn't then a logoff will also do the trick.

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, lock/unlock desktop doesn't work.  I guess there is no way to do it without completely logging off, then logging back on.

Answer (score 1):

`0x3e7` is the ID of the `SYSTEM` account, not the user you are trying to manage. Issue just `klist` to get the ID of your currently logged on user. You can issue just:

```
klist purge
```

to delete the cached kerberos tickets of the currently logged on user. After that, just access a ressource where you need a kerberos ticket (e. g. a network share) and you will get new cached kerberos tickets automatically. If you don't have a particular network share, access the default share of your domain (just your domain name): `\\mydomain.com`

---

If time does not matter and you just do not want to login again, you can wait at most 10 hours. That's the default time span, after which a kerberos ticket will automatically be renewed.